# How to Change Pixel Coordinates?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pixel, image-size

I wrote my own affine transformation code, but I want to save the new pixel coordinates I created to apply to the image I own, how can I do this. So how can I save the new pixel coordinate of an image to this image? Here is an example of the part I couldn't do in this code.

```
 img = cv2.imread("high1.jpeg", 0)
    new_pixel_coor = np.dot(coefficient_pixel_mat, unknown_parameters).astype(int)
        a = len(new_pixel_coor) // 2
        new_pixel_coor = new_pixel_coor.reshape((a, 2))

        print("Pixel Coordinates", "\n", new_pixel_coor)
        img2 = np.zeros((width, height, 3), dtype=np.uint)

        # There is an error. I could not do anything to save image
        for w in range(width):
            for h in range(height):
                img[w][h] = img2[new_pixel_coor]

        # Show and save the image
        cv2.imshow('OutputImage.jpg', img2)
        cv2.imwrite('OutputImage.jpg', img2)
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Code is very helpful when diagnosing or coming up with useful answers.

Comment: I updated my question by adding the code.The size of my new_pixel_coor array (3840000.1) so I reshape it with (a, 2) .In this way, it has reached the same size as the old pixel values, but I am not sure if this is the right way.